# Undefined SASS operation

Tags: css, for-loop, sass, syntax-error

I get and error when trying to execute this in a `@for` loop.
That's the error:

> Undefined operation "1 * calc(400px + 6%)".

And this is the line where the error comes from:

```
top: ($i + 1) % 3 * calc(400px + 6%);
```

And this is the `@for` loop:

```
@for $i from 0 through 9 {
  $card: "card-" + $i;
  .card-#{$i} {
    left: ($i + 1) % 3 * calc(20% + 6.66% * 2);
    top: ($i + 1) % 3 * calc(400px + 6%);
  }
}
```

For the `left` prop it works perfectly, just as I expected it to work, but I don't get what the error is about when comes to `top`.

Answer (score 5):

Put everything inside calc

```
@for $i from 0 through 9 {
  $card: "card-" + $i;
  .card-#{$i} {
    left: calc(#{($i + 1) % 3}*(20% + 6.66% * 2));
    top:  calc(#{($i + 1) % 3}*(400px + 6%));
  }
}
```